# How to execute a function which details are passed as parm in another function

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I need to execute an external function with params. The external function can be different so I am passing the details of external function with a main function is called. The main function takes object as params. So the information I am sending is transmitting correctly. However, when it's time to execute the external function the object key is trying to execute instead the value, hence I am getting error. What am I missing? Is there a better way to take resolve this issue?

HTML:

```
 <button onclick="fn.funcExt({name: 'foo', param: 'bar+baz'})">Check</button>
```

JS:

```
fn = (function(){

var publicAPI = {

    funcExt: function(o){return funcExt(o)}
};


////////////////////////////////////

function funcExt(o){
    console.log(o.name)
    console.log(o.param)
    o.name(o.param);
}



return publicAPI;
})();


/////////////////////////////////////////

function foo(s){
   alert('passed' + s);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/sf8f05fh/

Comment: What's the point of `funcExt: function(o){return funcExt(o)}` vs, say, `funcExt: funcExt`?

Comment: yea, it's same. That's how I like to organize my code as the original object is lot more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the external function is global, you'd access it as a property of the `window` object using square bracket notation so that the property name becomes the result of whatever expression you provide *(in this case, the `o.name` property)*.

```
window[o.name](o.param);
```

---

If it's in a global "namespace" object, you'd do the same.

```
SomeNS[o.name](o.param);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `foo` in quotes.

```
<button onclick="fn.funcExt({name: foo, param: 'bar+baz'})">Check</button>
```

This way, `o.name` will be the function, not the function name.

If you want to log the name of the function, you can do:

```
console.log(o.name.name);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9hdj9ovm/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess the global context, you could consider [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

You could modify the accepted answer solution to

```
this[o.name](o.param);
```

It will be `window` object by default, but if you want to be something else, you could alter your `publicAPI` object to something more meaningful:

```
var publicAPI = {
  funcExt: funcExt.bind(yourContext);
}
```

So the `this` above will point to `yourContext`.

Comment: This is awesome. I was looking for something like this where I don't tough the global context. Thanks much!!!